# If ssh connected user run ssh server again with another port?

Tags: linux, ssh

Let's say this situation.

Host - ssh server running (port 22)
      (allows "developer" user (having r/w at /temp/ directory), does not allow "root")

If somebody connect to the Host as "developer" via ssh:22.
And he copied sshd like openssh into /temp/ directory, and run sshd:3322 with configuration allowing root user without password.

Is it possible to connect the Host as root via ssh:3322 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The port number is irrelevant, what matters is the user who is running the server.

`sshd` has to be run by `root` in order to login to arbitrary accounts. If `sshd` is run by any other user, it doesn't have the privilege to call `setuid()` to change to another user, so it will only be able to login as the user who is running it (e.g. `developer`).